# Moment Js date different issue

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I have the below code. I am trying to get the difference between 2 date times. But the difference is being returned wrong.

```
var startDate = moment("14-Dec-2018 23:35:00", "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
var endDate = moment("15-Dec-2018 02:00:00", "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

var result = 'Diff: ' + endDate.diff(startDate, 'minutes');
```

Getting result = -1295

Expected result = 145

Kindly help.

Comment: What version of moment is this

Comment: Can you clarify if the answer helped you? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting of the date and time will give you problems in later version of MomentJS. A possible solution is to change your string that contains the date and time in an other format. I tested several versions of MomentJs and it seems you need a different pattern for your dates:

```
var startDate1 = moment("2018-12-14T23:35:00");
var endDate1 = moment("2018-12-15T02:00:00");
```

Compare MomentJS version 2.10.0:

```js
var startDate1 = moment("2018-12-14T23:35:00");
var endDate1 = moment("2018-12-15T02:00:00");
var result1 = endDate1.diff(startDate1, 'minutes');
console.log(result1);


var startDate2 = moment("14-Dec-2018 23:35:00", "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
var endDate2 = moment("15-Dec-2018 02:00:00", "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
var result2 = 'Diff: ' + endDate2.diff(startDate2, 'minutes');
console.log(result2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

with the output of version 2.22.2:

```js
var startDate1 = moment("2018-12-14T23:35:00");
var endDate1 = moment("2018-12-15T02:00:00");
var result1 = endDate1.diff(startDate1, 'minutes');
console.log(result1);


var startDate2 = moment("14-Dec-2018 23:35:00", "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
var endDate2 = moment("15-Dec-2018 02:00:00", "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
var result2 = 'Diff: ' + endDate2.diff(startDate2, 'minutes');
console.log(result2);
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The pattern I mentioned above is still correct, while your current one will be deprecated since it results in NaN (not a number).